# How to populate new rows to Footable with use Ajax and footable_redraw

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I'm trying to add records that's come from Ajax as respond. My codes are the following;

Ps: I can see ajax response with `alert` command properly.

### Html codes

```
<table id="seller-table" class="table" data-filter="#filter" data-page-size="5">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-toggle="true">ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Data as json

```
 var data = [{"id": 10, "date": "Mon Aug 04 2014 17:00:00"}, 
             {"id": 11, "date": "Tue Aug 05 2014 17:00:00"},
             {"id": 12, "date": "Wed Aug 06 2014 17:00:00"}];
```

### jQuery codes

```
    $.ajax({
        url : '/bid/find/',
        data: {  },
        success : function(data) {
            $('table tbody').append(data);
            $('table').trigger('footable_redraw');
        },
        error : function(xhr, statusText, error) { 
            alert("Error! Could not retrieve the data.");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array of objects returned by the AJAX call has to be converted to HTML elements before they can be added to the table:

```
$('table').footable();

function create_seller_table_row (item) {
    var row = $('<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>' + item.date + '</td></tr>');
    return row;
}

$.ajax({
    url : '/bid/find/',
    data: {  },
    success : function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, item){
            var row = create_seller_table_row(item);
            $('table tbody').append(row);
        });

        $('table').trigger('footable_initialize');
    },
    error : function(xhr, statusText, error) { 
        alert("Error! Could not retrieve the data.");
    }
});
```

Then use the [footable_initialize](http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/triggers.htm#docs)  trigger instead of the footable_redraw one.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrislaskey/0o4xLg9s/2/) of it in action.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I had tried to use this way "[FooTable Ajax Example](http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/ajax.htm)" I think I must add rows one by one like you've written. Because I have to continue :) Thanks again..

Comment: Glad to have helped! That example page is a little misleading, the live code in the "Demo" tab actually calls a `<tr>` creation function very similar to the one I show. But the code shown in the "Docs" tab doesn't show this step.